# IndentationError: expected an indented block (Weird)

Tags: python, file, indentation, os.system

I had almost finished on a software i was working on that should have worked but didn't. The software was intended to do the following:

1. Download a python script from the internet.
2. Automatically run it with the argument provided for the downloaded
   file

But an unusual error occurred in the process of running the downloaded script.

```
    python netscript.py [URL FOR TARGET FILE]  [ARGUMENTS FOR TARGET FILE|
```

Error:

```
    File "temp_dl/431341022.py", line 146

              ^
    IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from subprocess import call
    from sys import argv
    import urllib2
    import random
    import os


    script, url, ns_dledscript_arg =  argv
    def ns_runscript(ns_randfn, ns_dledscript_arg):
        print "Running downloaded content..."
        os.system("python temp_dl/%s.py %s" % (ns_randfn, ns_dledscript_arg))

    def ns_getcontent(url, ns_dledscript_arg):
        print "Getting content..."
        ns_openurl = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
        print "Filtering content..."
        #ns_filtered_data = re.sub( r'<[^>]*>', ' ', ns_openurl).strip()
        ns_filtered_data = BeautifulSoup(ns_openurl, "html.parser")
        ns_randfn = random.randrange(100000000, 999999999)
        file = open("temp_dl/%s.py" % (ns_randfn), "w") #Create writable file with random name.
        file.write("""%s""" % (ns_filtered_data)) #writes pretty code into the file with the random name.
        ns_question_viewdata = raw_input("Do you want to print data on console? 'y' or 'n': ")
        ns_runscript(ns_randfn, ns_dledscript_arg)
        if ns_question_viewdata == 'y':
            print ns_filtered_data
        elif ns_question_viewdata == 'n':
            exit()
        else:
            exit()

    ns_getcontent(url, ns_dledscript_arg)
```

Comment: The error seems to be in the downloaded script, not in your downloader.

Comment: Maybe it's because you indented everything by four spaces.  I got an IndentationError when I copied your code directly, but no such thing when I removed the four spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: My original does not have such indents i made a mistake filling out this question. I think user '9000' is correct. An intend error may exist in the downloaded script.

Comment: Can you check to make sure that you don't have any tabs instead in the source instead of spaces?  Running with `python -t` or `python -tt` should point out tab/space inconsistencies.

Comment: It may still be my mistake ill compare both the scripts i downloaded via the downloader and the script download via my browser.

Comment: Beautiful Soap doesn't filter the html out of the file properly...

Downloaded via my downloader: 
'while not found_path and attempts &lt; 10:'

should be : 'while not found_path and attempts < 10:'